# Exist or Exists?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a paper on the topic of “dharma”. I have written:

“Within these two categories **exists** all forms and definitions of dharma.”

I am stumped! Is it supposed to be **exist** or **exists**, and why?

Comment: The subject is the postposed 'all forms and definitions of dharma'. Though I can't see the logic, as it seems to mix differing concepts, it has to be considered plural and so mandates 'exist'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I understand now. I apologize for not replying sooner, but I am new here and didn’t realize you had responded.

Comment: To give a little background on my question, I am launching a monthly “Newsletter” regarding the ancient practice of “Bhakti-yoga”. In this first edition, I am writing more specifically about  its practice within the social-familial divisions (Varasram-dharma) of society.

Comment: I am stating that all sub-divisions of dharma, including all definitions and forms of dharma, are categorized under one of two headings, either “Naimittka” (impermanent) or “Nitya” (eternal). In my statement, I used “exists” to point out this fact, but wasn’t sure if it should be in the singular form or plural. I see now by the answers and explanations given that the plural form was/is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete subject of the sentence is "all forms and definitions of dharma." The simple subject is "all." The verb must agree with the simple subject "all." All can be singular or plural, depending upon what it represents. In this case "all" represents "forms and definitions," which is plural. The verb then is plural: exist.

Rearrange the sentence and it becomes clear.

All forms and definitions of dharma exist within these two categories.

Comment: Thank  you so much for taking the time to answer my question! Originally I had “exist“, but changed it because it didn’t quite sound right. Then after seeing “exists”, it didn’t sound right either. Then reading it again they both started sounding right and wrong at the same time!  Sheesh!

Your answer made it very clear, and I very much appreciate it! Thank you! I feel more confident now to change it back to what I originally had.

Comment: By the way, I’m taking your advice and rearranging the sentence. It really does make it become more clear! Hope that’s not plagiarism :-)

Comment: If that's plagiarism, we're all in trouble. Good luck with your paper.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with whether one is talking about substance or countable items.

Compare:

- All water **is** wet.
- All oceans **are** salty.

Water is a continuous substance.  No matter how much of it one has, it is still singular.

Oceans are discrete things.  It's possible to have one ocean, or two oceans, or seventeen oceans, but it's not possible to have two and a half oceans.  Unless there is only one, oceans are plural.

Similarly:

- The two and a half litres of milk that he poured **is** more than enough.
- The four litres of milk **are** in the fridge door.

The first is an amount of milk, the second is a number of cartons of milk.

In the question, "*all forms and definitions*" might involve a large number, but it will still be an integral number.  So unless it is 1, it is plural, and so "*exist*", not "*exists*", is appropriate.

Comment: Perfect explanation! It’s just what I needed to understand a little bit more in depth. I really appreciate you taking the time.